# AWS Node 2 Lambda which shares the db postgres code not returning value for the second lambda?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, aws-lambda, pg-promise

Am having the following project structure for my Node Ts Lambda

project-root/
│
├── src/
│   ├── lambda1/
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── Service.ts
│   │   ├── package.json.
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   │
│   ├── lambda2/
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── Service.json
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   │
│   └── shared/
│       ├── dbconnect.ts
│       ├── constants.ts
│       └──
│
├── tsconfig.json
├── package.json

in my shared dbconnect.ts having the db connection code and a method to execute function using pgpromise packages.

**Actual Issue**
after deploying the 2 lambdas first lambda can successfully return data, but second lambda neither returning any value nor throwing any errors below is the logs for the second lambda and highlighted the console.log info in BOLD

> INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:20.v15 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2::runtime:0856f5d760b75612d4aa6b5feda50bafc1ce3ba07c036cbd0abc585dc28fb870
> START RequestId: 85af3fa6-2044-4664-9d67-9890be0a088a Version: $LATEST
> 2024-02-16T10:59:14.484Z    85af3fa6-2044-4664-9d67-9890be0a088a    **INFO  Inside GetLegalDashBoardData**
> 2024-02-16T10:59:14.523Z    85af3fa6-2044-4664-9d67-9890be0a088a    **INFO  Inside Service connectionString**
> 2024-02-16T10:59:14.524Z    85af3fa6-2044-4664-9d67-9890be0a088a    **INFO  Inside ConnectToDatabase**
> 2024-02-16T10:59:14.726Z    85af3fa6-2044-4664-9d67-9890be0a088a    **INFO  Inside ConnectToDatabase before return**
> 2024-02-16T10:59:14.726Z    85af3fa6-2044-4664-9d67-9890be0a088a    **INFO  After ConnectToDatabase**
> END RequestId: 85af3fa6-2044-4664-9d67-9890be0a088a
> REPORT RequestId: 85af3fa6-2044-4664-9d67-9890be0a088a  Duration: 525.35 ms Billed Duration: 526 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 76 MB  Init Duration: 191.40 ms

Here is my DBConnection.ts Code what I have Tried

```
    import { IDatabase, IMain } from 'pg-promise';
    import pgpromise from 'pg-promise';

    async function ConnectToDatabase(user: string, password: string, host: string, port: number, database: string): Promise<IDatabase<any>> {
    try {
        console.log("Inside ConnectToDatabase");
        const pgp = pgpromise();
        const connectionOptions = {
            host: host,
            port: port,
            database: database,
            user: user,
            password: password,
        };

        const dbClient = pgp(connectionOptions)
        console.log("Inside ConnectToDatabase before return");
        return dbClient;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to the database:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

    export async function ExecuteFunction(query: string, connectionParams: any) {
    try {
        const dbCreds = JSON.parse(connectionParams);
        const plsqlQuery: any = JSON.parse(query)
        const dbInstance = await ConnectToDatabase(dbCreds.user, dbCreds.password, dbCreds.host, dbCreds.port, dbCreds.database);
        console.log(`After ConnectToDatabase`)
        const result = dbInstance.func(plsqlQuery.funcName, plsqlQuery.params);
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('ExecuteFunction Error in Fetching Records From the database:', error);
        throw error;
    }
    }
```

Service.ts file where am calling the dbconnect.ts method to connect to db and execute function and return the result

```
import { config } from '../../../shared/config/whub_config';
import { ExecuteFunction } from '../../../shared/data_access/whub_data_service';
export async function GetLegalDashBoardData() {
    console.log("Inside GetLegalDashBoardData")
    try {

        const dbCred: any = GetHubDBCredentials();
        const query: any = {
            funcName: `${config.WHUB_LEGAL_SCHEMA}.${config.LEGAL_GET_DASHBOARD_DATA}`,
            params:"test"
        }
        console.log(`Inside Service connectionString`)
        const result = await ExecuteFunction(JSON.stringify(query),JSON.stringify(dbCred));
         return result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error executing query', error);
        console.log('Error executing query', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```

Sorry if it's a duplicate question, please help me to resolve this issue, thanks in advance

Comment: @cow, have deleted the 2 duplicated questions, thanks for correcting me

Comment: `ConnectToDatabase` doesn't connect to the database, and it doesn't return a promise, so use of `await` for its output is pointless.

Comment: yep but why it's not connecting to database atleast it should throw an error right

Answer (score 0):

Since `func` [returns a Promise](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#func), shouldn't you be using `await` when you call it?

Comment: tried that still no luck

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling `GetLegalDashBoardData`? Have you tried adding debugging code to see what is in `result` after your calls to `dbInstance.func` and/or after `ExecuteFunction`? Please show those results as well.

Comment: the index.ts is calling the GetLegalDashBoardData it's pretty straightforward one, the result is not even printing in the ExecuteFunction itself dbInstance.func is not at all called after this         const dbInstance = await ConnectToDatabase(dbCreds.user, dbCreds.password, dbCreds.host, dbCreds.port, dbCreds.database);

Comment: I understand, and can take your word for it. However, to get good help, you do need to share your complete code including any updates you've made (I asked you to add `await`, and @vitaly-t encouraged you to remove the `await` for `ConnectToDatabase`) and update the log output following an execution of the Lambda with those changes made.